# Google Compute Engine is not responding

Tags: google-compute-engine

My GCP server is down. It was working last day. I can see the server in VM Instances but can not connect using SSH. All the client websites are down.

Can any one help ?

Comment: Nmap port scanner is showing filtered on ssh port

Answer (score 2):

There is several reasons this could happen:

- If your [disk is full](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk)
- [sshd deamon](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) isn't configured properly
- If [OS login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#enable_oslogin) is enabled on your instance
- A [firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/configuring-firewall-rules) block port 20

Sometimes, you see some connection errors in the [console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connectserialconsole), that worth to take a look.

EDIT:

I will need additional information if that still not working;

1. Take a look to your [serial console logs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connectserialconsole) and tell me if you have any relevant logs that can help like a kernel panic, issue with networking, permission denied, etc
2. Use [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) and try to connect to your VM instance with these commands:

   - gcloud compute firewall-rules create --network=default default-allow-ssh --allow tcp:22
   - gcloud compute ssh YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME --zone YOUR_ZONE -- -vvv

If you can't connect from cloud shell, try to ping your VM instance (internal IP & external IP)

3. I highly recommend to delete your screenshots showing information about your VM instance (Firewall rules, Project name, nmap scans, etc).

Comment: Hi Bruno, Thanks for your response. 
1. disk is not full .. It had lots of space left
2. sshd daemon was working the last day
3. I don't know about it .. I use browser ssh and have enabled Password so I use it from my terminal of ubuntu
4. Yes this seems like it .. as nmap scanner gives all the port as filtered which means its blocked by firewall .. But how can I get my control back .. Port 80, 22 all blocked .. So I am cluseless

Comment: And since you are from Google Cloud Support .. can you tell be best way to get support on these types of issues?

Comment: Based on the port scan screenshot you provided, your SSH port state is filtered. That mean nmap are not able to determine if the port is open or close [1].
You should take a look to this interface [2] on Google Console to verify if any rule allow/deny the SSH port. 

[1] https://wiki.onap.org/display/DW/Nmap
[2] https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls

Comment: I found an awesome guide about How-to configure firewall rules on geekflare.com [3] if you are certain that issue come from a firewall rule. This is not from the Google official documentation but the guide is very well done and easy to understand. From the same guide, you will found a link leading to how to change the SSH default port [4], that could be useful to verify your own SSH configuration on your server.

[3] https://geekflare.com/gcp-firewall-configuration/
[4] https://geekflare.com/cloud-vm-security-guide/#1-Changing-SSH-Default-Port

Comment: If that is still not working, could you tell me if the SSH button from Google Console works for your VM instance [5][6]?

Regarding your question about GCP support, I think Stackoverflow & Serverfault are both excellent community support. In the other hand, if you looking for an Enterprise Support grade with SLA, phone support, etc, I suggest you this documentation [7].

[5] https://console.cloud.google.com/compute
[6] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#gcetools
[7] https://cloud.google.com/support/

Comment: Thanks a lot Bruno. 

I am deleting the comments with images.

I saw your message regarding the gcloud command a bit late but still lot of thanks for your time.

My issue resolved just by stopping and starting the instance again. Meanwhile I had to make my IP static to avoid IP change at start.