# Unable to connect with Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

My GCP Compute engine is down. In GCP console it is up and running. It is an Ubuntu 18.04 server with 0.6GB memory(an always free tier compute engine). It was not restarted for more than couple of months. The system usage was around 60% last checked.  I have already checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58409720/google-compute-engine-is-not-responding). And none of them seems valid for me(seems so).

1. Free disk stands at 54%.
2. SSH perfectly configured.
3. No firewall issue.

It just seemed the VM stopped responding putting the hosted url down. When I checked Compute engine monitoring tabs, all the graphs were normal without any visible changes. I even checked the logging but no system crash kind of logs were present. I stopped and restarted the compute engine, and it started working perfectly, as nothing happened. In AWS, the VM instance failed System Reachability tests in such scenarios.

Does GCP has something similar like AWS system reachability test?

Any possible logs or something, by which I can understand the reason why the Compute Engine stopped responding?

Comment: Please check [Serial port 1 (console) logs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connectserialconsole) and update your question with output. Can restart your VM and collect full startup log from Serial port 1 (console)?

Answer (score 2):

There are different kinds of test with custom scenarios in your project , please find it on reference link [1]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/network-intelligence-center/docs/connectivity-tests/how-to/running-connectivity-tests